# how to name buffers (*shell*)

Tags: buffers, shell

I'm interested in naming Emacs buffers. In particular I'd like to give names to `shell` buffers that I've started. That way I can easily tell them apart when switching buffers.

Comment: What about using the current directory of the shell?

Comment: I would normally call `C-u M-x shell` - in this way Emacs offers to name the buffer it creates. But if I forget, there's always the `M-x rename-buffer`. Or are you asking for an advise on what that name should be?

Comment: @wvxvw: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: FWIW, I bind `rename-buffer` to a key (and I use it fairly often).

Comment: @Drew I'm not sure if OP wants the technical "how to rename shell buffer" answer, or "what should I name shell buffer to make it unique / meaningfull" kind of answer (eg. Emacs will append `<...>` to buffer names if both are visiting a file with the same name based on some quite complex heuristic). In the later case, I don't quite have a good answer, but one possibility would be to update the name of the buffer using some meaningful part of the shell command ran in that buffer.

Answer (score 14):

Go to the buffer you want to rename, in your case `*shell*`. Then type `M-x rename-buffer` and enter the new name for this buffer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Helm`. Just press <kbd>M-R</kbd> in helm buffer list.

It calls [helm-buffer-run-rename-buffer](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/4ff354efb6b24044fd38b725b61d470bd5423265/helm-buffers.el#L227) which will call emacs `rename-buffer` function.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to your init.el, and create a keybinding:

```
(defun unique-shell ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'shell)
  (rename-uniquely))

(global-set-key "\C-z" 'unique-shell)
```

Now every time you press ctrl+z, it will launch a shell with a new name.

Comment: I suppose `(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'rename-uniquely)` would work too.

Comment: Wouldn't the (interactive) line already handle the (call-interactively...) part, or do these do something different?

Comment: You need the interactive call to use the optional argument (e.g. `C-u M-x unique-shell`). I was also getting an error from `(advice-add 'shell :after (lambda (_)...)`, but I see the argument is optional so I probably should've used `(advice-add 'shell :after (lambda (&optional _)...)`.